# Sharepoint List View Threshold and Item Limit setting

Tags: sharepoint

I have read a lot about the list view threshold. I have indexed the appropriate meta data columns to help. I have placed mandatory web part filters on web pages. I think I am going to be able to control the view pretty well.

Should a user try to get an "All Items View" will the "Item Limit" in the view settings keep the view from exceeding the threshold?  I could not find a straight or understandable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I only know the answer for SharePoint 2010. From your question is not clear, which version you are using.

But, the item limit in the view will not protect you from exceeding the threshold. This is a very, very complicated topic with the `List View Threshold`.

You should read this

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-sharepoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59

Comment: I am using SP 2010 on prem soon to migrate to SP 2016, like with a month or two.